# How are rational numbers implemented in Julia

Tags: julia, programming-languages, rational-number

Are the numerator and denominator stored as integers? Specifically, how are implemented the basic operations: sum, subtraction, multiplication, division?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/248bbf6d61b643d0101bf96093cd7621e5bcf477/base/rational.jl#L9-L15

the code is fairly readable, in short:

```
struct Rational{T<:Integer} <: Real
```

means that both numerator and denominator have the same type, and that type is `<: Integer`.

---

if you want to know how some operations are implemented, try running this in your REPL:

```
julia> @edit 1//2 + 3//4
```

it should bring you to https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/248bbf6d61b643d0101bf96093cd7621e5bcf477/base/rational.jl#L285

Comment: Yes, @edit is one of my favourite macros in Julia 

Answer (score 2):

Even a faster and easier way to understand what is going on in Julia is just to use the `dump` command such as:

```
julia> dump(3//4)
Rational{Int64}
  num: Int64 3
  den: Int64 4
```